# awk/sed/grep/perl using field separator then only showing specific lines

Tags: regex, bash, perl, awk, sed

Recently I learned that shairport (airplay emulator) now creates a fifo file that pipes metadata in this format:

```
   artist=Justin Bieber
   title=Baby
   album=My World 2.0
   artwork=cover-2de1df4b978034bcd789ea10b1111a.jpg
   genre=Pop
   comment=
```

I have an lcd display I'd like to send it to, but **I'm trying to parse it out to show basically this:**

```
   Justin Bieber
   Baby
   My World 2.0
```

I tried using awk to get me the above results, but if anyone has any suggestions using sed, grep, perl or anything else, I'm open to it!

Anyways, here's a bunch of stuff that I've tried so far:

```
awk -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

to get it to show:

```
   Justin Bieber
   Baby
   My World 2.0
   cover-2de1df4b978034bcd789ea10b1111a.jpg
   Pop
```

Cool almost there, but I don't really need to show the artwork, genre, and comment.

This is the command I used to filter out those extra fields:

```
awk '!/artwork=/ && !/genre=/ && !/comment=/ && /./'
```

To print this:

```
   artist=Justin Bieber
   title=Baby
   album=My World 2.0
```

Now I just need to combine the two, so I tried this (not to mention a bunch of other variations):

```
awk '!/artwork=/ && !/genre=/ && !/comment=/ && /./' && -F"=" '{print $2}'
```

But I get the same results as above:

```
   artist=Justin Bieber
   title=Baby
   album=My World 2.0
```

I know I'm missing something very basic, but I'm just completely stuck.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn' stand: it's the first line of the file that `awk` and all other scripting languages with a taste in music won't accept as valid input EVER ;)

Comment: Hah, I thought the people of stackoverflow would get a kick out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there, you need to put `-F"="` at the start.

```
$ awk -F"=" '!/artwork=/ && !/genre=/ && !/comment=/{print $2}' file
Justin Bieber
Baby
My World 2.0
```

OR

The below awk would take only the first three rows,

```
$ awk -F"=" 'NR<4{print $2}' file
Justin Bieber
Baby
My World 2.0
```

Comment: Thank you! I felt like I was close, but just couldn't get the right combination of things. I had tried putting the `-F"="`at the beginning of the command at one point, but didn't have the `{print $2}` placed correctly. My LCD is now displaying my tracks pretty nicely now!

Answer (score 2):

Just use regex power to combine all conditions into one:

```
awk -F"=" '!($1 ~ /^(artwork|genre|comment|)$/) {print $2}' file
```

Comment: Thank you also! When I tested this one, I couldn't get the blank rows to filter out. I tried modifying it slightly by doing this: `(artwork|genre|comment|.)`, but that's probably really illogical.

Comment: Just make it: `awk -F"=" '!($1 ~ /^(artwork|genre|comment|)$/) {print $2}' file` to ignore blank lines.

Comment: Ah thank you. This version removed the blank rows. I'm not sure why I didn't notice the first recommendation from Avinash also didn't remove the blank rows. Turns out I needed those blank rows because my LCD display shows 4 rows. For posterity: `awk -F"=" '!($1 ~ /^(artwork|genre|comment)/) {print $2}'`

Comment: Ok that's great to know your problem got solved. You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perl version

```
perl -F/=/ -lane 'print $F[1] if $F[0] =~ /artist|title|album/' file
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested this version out also. It printed fine in the terminal, but it didn't seem to want to pipe to my LCD. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Using a perl one-liner

```
perl -ne 'print if s/(artwork|genre|comment)=//' file
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and `cut` :

```
grep -Ev "(artwork|genre|comment)" file | cut -d= -f 2
Justin Bieber
Baby
My World 2.0
```

Using `perl` :

```
perl -ne  '!/(artwork|genre|comment)/ && s/.*=(.*)/$1/g && print' file
```